# How can I get a post field value using javascript?

Tags: posts, custom-field, javascript

Background: I have a page with Essential Grid items, which are post thumbnails. Because ESS is slightly limited, I want to create a JS function, which will get the post meta fields called "address1" and "address2".

I have the completed the code which gets the post ID depending on the clicked item.

```
$('.eg-item-skin-1-element-11').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');

    var postId = id.replace('eg-1-post-id-', '');

    jQuery('.eModal-1').click();

    console.log(postId);

});
```

Now I would like to use the post ID to retrieve the values of `address1` and `address2` post fields. I have read about the WP REST API, but the documentation is scarce. Can I use the API and a JS ajax function to get the two values?

These values will then dynamically be placed into `eModal-1` upon click, so that I don't have to create a modal for each post and dozens of modals aren't pre-loaded on each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use the API and a JS ajax function to get the two values?

Yes, absolutely.

**Step 1: (PHP)** Registers the custom fields (i.e. add them to the WordPress REST API response for [Posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#schema))

```
register_meta( 'post', 'address1', [
    'type'         => 'string', // string/boolean/integer/number
    'single'       => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
] );

register_meta( 'post', 'address2', [
    'type'         => 'string',
    'single'       => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
] );
```

See [Modifying Responses | REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#read-and-write-a-post-meta-field-in-post-responses) and [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/#parameters).

**Step 2 (PHP):** Loads the official client/JS library

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' );
} );
```

See [Backbone JavaScript Client | REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/).

**Step 3:** Add the JS code

.. which is as simple as: (refer to your *question* for the `postId` variable)

```
var post = new wp.api.models.Post( { id: postId } );

post.fetch().done( function(){
    // Use `post.getMeta( 'KEY' )` to retrieve the meta value.
    alert( post.getMeta( 'address1' ) );
    alert( post.getMeta( 'address2' ) );
} );
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/#model-examples ..

---

**UPDATE:** An alternative to the `wp-api` script.

If you *don't* want to use the official client/JS library, or if you want just a simple jQuery script, then...

**Step 2:**

***Don't* queue/load the `wp-api` script.**

Add this somewhere on the page: *(the variable name can be changed, but make sure to also change the one in the JS code in step #3)*

```
<script>
var restApiSettings = {
    nonce: '<?= wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ) ?>',
    root: '<?= esc_url_raw( rest_url( 'wp/v2' ) ) ?>'
};
</script>
```

Or with PHP/WordPress, use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) like the official client/JS library does it.

```
wp_localize_script( 'your-script', 'restApiSettings', [
    'root'  => esc_url_raw( rest_url( 'wp/v2' ) ),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
] );
```

**Step 3:** The JS/jQuery code:

```
jQuery.get( restApiSettings.root + '/posts/' + postId, {
    _wpnonce: restApiSettings.nonce
}, function( res ){
    if ( res.meta ) {
        alert( res.meta.address1 );
        alert( res.meta.address2 );
    }
} );
```